# Unity 2021.3.4f1 Gradle Build failed

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, apk

Unity 2021.3.4f1 is giving me these errors while building an apk

```
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1
> incompatible Daemon could not be
> reused, use --status for details
> 
> > Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option setting
> 'android.enableR8=false' is
> deprecated. It will be removed in
> version 5.0 of the Android Gradle
> plugin. You will no longer be able to
> disable R8 Exception while marshalling
> C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only
> 
> > Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> > Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> > Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> > Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> > Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> > Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> > Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> > Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> > Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> > Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> > Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> > Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> > Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> > Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> > Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> > Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> > Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> 
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> 
> > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> > Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> > Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> > Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> > Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED 45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
> 
> UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu
> (object,string[],int)
```

The second error is

```
Note: D:\Unity Development\EndMan 1\EndMan1\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Unity Development\EndMan 1\EndMan1\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Samprit Hazra\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 25s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

The third error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\Unity Development\EndMan 1\EndMan1\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Unity Development\EndMan 1\EndMan1\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Samprit Hazra\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 25s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath,
```

My JDK Version is JDK-18 and the unity version is 2021.3.4f1 64bit i have been working in a project since many days and everything worked fine but when i tried to build the apk unity threw at error at me which is related to gradle only
Fast reply appreciated

Comment: Hi Samprit , Did you tried to build an android build with custom Keystore. As it worked for me I was facing same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Man, Java developer's are so deceptively verbose...
In this (pile of garbage) log, what's really important is

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Samprit Hazra\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

*Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Samprit Hazra.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format*

You might want to take a look to your file using http://keystore-explorer.org/ and see if something is wrong with it.

Comment: Incredible... I was hunting through a dozen other errors, and this was certainly the main culprit. Good looking out.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create a custom Keystore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32290967)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it generate a new keystore that isn't busted.

- Close Unity
- Browse to C:\Users\Username.android
- Move or delete the debug.keystore/lock
- Build will be successful