# Gradle and SDK build failed

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

Just started using unity, have no idea what to do with that:CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"
```

Also i am getting another error with SDK:

```
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544504/unity-2021-3-4f1-gradle-build-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, download and install android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio

Go to unity. Then on build settings select "Export Project".
Then click "Export project".

Open android studio. Then open your newly exported project.
Build that projcet from android studio.

It might work